# App stops working after a function is called from another function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a kind of a brain trainer app, just for practice. There are two numbers which are added or substracted and we need to guess the result. There are four buttons, in one is the correct value, and the other three are random numbers. I have a function setQuestion() that does all that.
When I press some of these buttons, it checks if the numbers are right and updates the score. And it should call the function setQuestion() so it creates new values, but for some reason the app crashes after I click a button.

The setQuestion function works, because it is run when the app is opened.
Here is the code for those two functions.

```
public void setQuestion(){
    int firstNumber = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(101);
    int secondNumber = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(101);
    int operation = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(2);
    TextView firstNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
    TextView secondNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);
    TextView operationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.operation);
    if(operation == 0){
        sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        operationTextView.setText("+");
    }
    else{
        while (secondNumber > firstNumber){
            secondNumber = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(101);
        }
        operationTextView.setText("-");
        sum = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    }
    firstNumberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(firstNumber));
    secondNumberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(secondNumber));
    int operation1 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(2);
    int operation2 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(2);
    int operation3 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(2);
    int answer1 = 0;
    int answer2 = 0;
    int answer3 = 0;
    switch (operation1){
        case 0:
            answer1 = sum + randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(9) +1 +1;
        break;
        case 1:
            int temp = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(9) +1;
            if(sum > temp){
                answer1 = sum - temp;
            }
            else{
                answer1 = temp;
            }

    }

    switch (operation2){
        case 0:
            answer2 = sum + randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(9) +1;
            break;
        case 1:
            int temp = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(9) +1;
            if(sum > temp){
                answer2 = sum - temp;
            }
            else{
                answer2 = temp;
            }

    }

    switch (operation3){
        case 0:
            answer3 = sum + randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(9) +1;
            break;
        case 1:
            int temp = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(9) +1;
            if(sum > temp){
                answer3 = sum - temp;
            }
            else{
                answer3 = temp;
            }

    }
    buttonMap.add(0);
    buttonMap.add(1);
    buttonMap.add(2);
    buttonMap.add(3);
    Collections.shuffle(buttonMap);

    int[] valArray = {sum, answer1, answer2, answer3};

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonMap.size(); i++) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("b"+buttonMap.get(i), "id", getPackageName());
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(id);
        button.setText(String.valueOf(valArray[i]));
    }




}
```

And the other:

```
public void answer(View view){
    Button clickedButton = (Button) view;
    String clickedValue = clickedButton.getText().toString();
    int clickedValueInt = Integer.parseInt(clickedValue);
    TextView allQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalQuestions);
    numberOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(allQuestion.getText().toString());
    TextView correctQuestions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctQuestions);
    numberOfCorrectQuestions = Integer.parseInt(correctQuestions.getText().toString());
    if(clickedValueInt == sum){
        numberOfCorrectQuestions++;
        correctQuestions.setText(String.valueOf(numberOfCorrectQuestions));
    }
    System.out.println(numberOfCorrectQuestions);
    numberOfQuestions++;
    allQuestion.setText(String.valueOf(numberOfQuestions));
    setQuestion();
}
```

And here is text from logcat.

02-26 02:34:19.965 305-305/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/18289/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-26 02:34:19.987 850-6076/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
02-26 02:34:20.167 850-1922/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
02-26 02:34:20.221 27755-27832/? E/PackageLogInfoManager: checkPackageLogState, cr: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@bb1c2fa, packageNames: null
02-26 02:34:20.327 18468-18486/? E/linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/23') failed: Permission denied [fd=23]
02-26 02:34:20.328 18468-18486/? E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/system/lib64/hw/gralloc.hi6250.so". Will use given name.
02-26 02:34:20.335 18468-18486/? E/linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/23') failed: Permission denied [fd=23]
02-26 02:34:20.335 18468-18486/? E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "libion.so". Will use given name.
02-26 02:34:20.461 18468-18468/? E/TotemWeather: Utils error:getWidgetShowCityInfo return myLocation
02-26 02:34:20.463 18468-18485/? E/TotemWeather: Utils error:getWidgetShowCityInfo return myLocation
02-26 02:34:20.522 9539-9608/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
02-26 02:34:20.525 18468-18468/? E/TotemWeather: Utils error:getWidgetShowCityInfo return myLocation
02-26 02:34:20.929 1854-1854/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: invalidateCache set mNeedToastTableFull

Comment: woah that's a big function

Comment: In my defense I started Android and java 5 days ago. But I know that I should make more smaller function, right?

Answer (score 0):

Check if all texts from TextViews can be converted to integers. Could you add the stack trace to your question?

Comment: That works, the text in the TextViews changes, but the app crashes.

Comment: Oh and, I took a look at that, but there is just so much text there I don't know where to look. Like I said, I started with Android and Java 5 days ago.

Comment: As I understood, the app crashes when you press a button, and when you press a button the 'answer()' method is called, right?

Comment: Exacly. And it does everything it should, but when it calls the setQuestion() it crashes.

Comment: Could you paste all that text in your question please? It will be a lot easier to solve the problem.

Comment: From logcat you mean?

Comment: Yep, it is all red and have some kind of link at the end of each line

Comment: Alright, I debuged the app again, I will paste everthing from after the crash.

Comment: It's not the right log, look at the top of logcat window on the left side, there should be your device in a drop down and on the right of device name you need to select your application name in order to see logs only for it and not all logs from device

Comment: I tried, and one of two things happen. Either it shows what I already posted, or it is completly blank.

Comment: Check at the right top side than to see if there are no filters set for logs

Comment: Hey, I have figured out where I was wrong, but thank you for your time! Should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 0):

The errror was this. I have an arrayList called buttonMap which I use for accessing buttons. And every time I called the setQuestion() method, it added 4 values (0,1,2,3). I just removed this code

```
buttonMap.add(0);
    buttonMap.add(1);
    buttonMap.add(2);
    buttonMap.add(3);
```

from the method and it all works.